# Using Managed Class Method as Callback

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, marshalling

I'm currently working on a little Midi Project and just now I'm writing a little "SharpMidi" Library in C++/Cli to make it easier for me to use native Midi functions from Managed code.

I'm now stuck on the midiInOpen Function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

As you can see from the documentation, this function requires an unmanaged function as Callback and optional instance data.

I managed to convert a Managed Function Pointer to an unmanaged Function Pointer using
`System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`
but I now have problems converting the `this` Pointer from my managed class to an unmanaged Pointer, I don't even know if its possibly they way I want it to work.

```
HMIDIIN _midiInDevice;

void MidiInProcNative(HMIDIIN midiInDevice, UINT msg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2);
delegate void MidiInProc(HMIDIIN midiInDevice, UINT msg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2);

MidiInProc^ _midiInProc;

...

_midiInProc = gcnew MidiInDevice::MidiInProc(this, &MidiInDevice::MidiInProcNative);

cli::pin_ptr<HMIDIIN> midiInDevPtr = &_midiInDevice;
pin_ptr<???> thisPtr = this; // This is the line I'm struggling with
MMRESULT result = midiInOpen(midiInDevPtr, devId, (DWORD_PTR)System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(_midiInProc).ToPointer(), thisPtr, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
```

As you can see I have experimented with pin_ptrs but I don't think this will work as the this pointer can't be used to initialize any pin_ptr.

I hope I could make clear what I want to try to achieve and maybe somebody can help me out.
Regards,
Xaser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I now have problems converting the this Pointer from my managed class to an unmanaged Pointer

Just don't, there's no need for it.  The *dwCallbackInstance* argument of miniInOpen() is a convenience argument for native C++.  You get it back in the static callback function, let's you call an instance method of a C++ class.

But delegates are far more powerful than member function pointers, they already encapsulate *this*.  A delegate constructor takes *two* arguments, the target object and the target method.  So that it can automatically call an instance method.  You already took advantage of that, you indeed passed *this* as the first argument.  So you can be sure that your MidiInProcNative() instance method uses the proper object reference.

Just pass nullptr for the argument.

Comment: Thanks for that, I think I got the use of dwCallbackInstance wrong, I thought the Midi Function would then Call dwCallbackInstance->CallbackFunc or something like this. I will mark your answer once I successufully tested it.